# Listbox selectedindex property change doesn't update the UI

Tags: scripting, javascript

Using javascript, I am trying to change the selection of the listbox item like this:

```
 function selectFirstActiveListItem(oListBox)
    {
         for (var i = 0; i < oListBox.options.length; i++)
         {
            oListBox.selectedIndex = i;                

            var szStatus = GetDomboBoxItemAttribute("Status", m_pdocConnectType.getXMLDOM(), oListBox);

            if ("Enabled" == szStatus)
                return;
         }
         oListBox.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Though the index correctly changes at the background, but it is not reflected on the UI. The listbox still shows the old selection.

What's going wrong?

Comment: would this code reflect the new index selection on the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! That was working and showing the correct result. My take on the behavior was incorrect there.

Answer (score 3):

try this instead:

```
oListBox.options[i].selected = true;
```